# Is it Friday yet?

Tags: c++, beginner, datetime, homework

This is the first program that I have written in my C++ saga that I actually think is useful.  The description for this assignment is kinda long and mundane though:

> Write a program that inputs a date (for example: July 4, 2008) and
>   outputs the day of the week that corresponds to that date.  The
>   following algorithm is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week).  The implementation will
>   require several functions.
>
> - `bool isLeapYear(int year);`
>
>   This function should return `true` if `year` is a leap year and    `false` if it is not.  Here is the pseudo code to determine a leap    year:
>
>   ```
>   leap_year = (year divisible by 400) or (year divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100)
>   ```
> - `int getCenturyValue(int year);`
>
>   This function should take the first two digits of the year (that is, the century), divide by \$ 4 \$, and save the remainder.  Subtract the remainder from \$ 3 \$ and return this value multiplied by \$ 2 \$.  For example, the year \$ 2008 \$ becomes \$ \dfrac{20}{4} = 5 \$ with a remainder of \$ 0 \$. \$ 3 - 0 = 3 \$.  Return \$ 3 \cdot 2 = 6 \$.
> - `int getYearValue(int year);`
>
>   This functions computes a value based on the years since the beginning of the century.  First, extract the last two digits of the year.  For example, \$ 08 \$ is extracted for \$ 2008 \$.  Next, factor in leap years.  Divide the value from the previous step by \$ 4 \$ and discard the remainder.  Add the two results together and return this value.  For example, from \$ 2008 \$ we extract \$ 08 \$.  Then \$ \dfrac{8}{4} = 2 \$ with a remainder of \$ 0 \$. Return \$ 2 + 8 = 10 \$.
> - `int getMonthValue(int month, int year);`
>
>   This function should return a value based on the table below and will require invoking the `isLeapYear()` function.
>
>   $$ 
>        \newcommand\T{\Rule{0pt}{1em}{.5em}}
>        \begin{array}{|c|c|}
>        \hline \textbf{Month} & \textbf{Return Value} \\\hline
>          \text{January} \T & 0 \left(6 \text{ if year is a leap year} \right) \\\hline
>          \text{February} \T & 3 \left(2 \text{ if year is a leap year} \right)  \\\hline
>          \text{March} \T & 3  \\\hline
>          \text{April} \T & 6  \\\hline
>          \text{May} \T & 1  \\\hline
>          \text{June} \T & 4  \\\hline
>          \text{July} \T & 6  \\\hline
>          \text{August} \T & 2  \\\hline
>          \text{September} \T & 5  \\\hline
>          \text{October} \T & 0  \\\hline
>          \text{November} \T & 3  \\\hline
>          \text{December} \T & 5  \\\hline
>        \end{array}
>        $$
> - Finally, to compute the day of the week, compute the sum of the date's day plus the values returned by `getMonthValue`, `getYearValue`, and `getCenturyValue`.  Divide the sum by \$ 7 \$ and compute the remainder.  A remainder of \$ 0 \$ corresponds to Sunday, \$ 1 \$ corresponds to Monday, etc., up to \$ 6 \$, which corresponds to Saturday.  For example, the date July 4, 2008 should be computed as (day of month) + (getMonthValue) + (getYearValue) + (getCenturyValue) = \$ 4 + 6 + 10 + 6 = 26 \$.  \$ \dfrac{26}{7} = 3 \$ with a remainder of \$ 5 \$.  The fifth day of the week corresponds to Friday.
>
> Your program should allow the user to enter any date and output the
>   corresponding day of the week in English.
>
> This program should include a `void` function named `getInput` that
>   prompts the user for the date and returns the month, day, and year
>   using pass-by-reference parameters.  You may choose to have the user
>   enter the date's month as either a number (1-12) or a month name.

**`dayOfWeek.cpp`**:

```
/**
 * @file dayOfWeek.cpp
 * @brief Computes the day of the week given a certain date
 * @author syb0rg
 * @date 10/23/14
 */

#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

enum Months {None, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December};
std::string *weekDays = new std::string[7] {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

/**
 * Makes sure data isn't malicious, and signals user to re-enter proper data if invalid
 */
size_t getSanitizedNum()
{
    size_t input = 0;
    while(!(std::cin >> input))
    {
        // clear the error flag that was set so that future I/O operations will work correctly
        std::cin.clear();
        // skips to the next newline
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid input.  Please enter a positive number: ";
    }
    return input;
}

/**
 * Safetly grabs and returns a lowercase version of the character (if the lowercase exists)
 */
char32_t getSanitizedChar()
{
    // absorb newline character (if existant) from previous input
    if('\n' == std::cin.peek()) std::cin.ignore();
    return std::tolower(std::cin.get());
}

bool isLeapYear(const int year)
{
    if (0 == (year % 400) || (0 == (year % 4) && (year % 100))) return true;
    else return false;
}

int getCenturyValue(const size_t year)
{
    return (2 * (3 - div(year / 100, 4).rem));
}

int getYearValue(const size_t year)
{
    int mod = year % 100;
    return (mod + div(mod, 4).quot);
}

int getMonthValue(const size_t month, const size_t year)
{
    switch (month) {
        case January:
            if (isLeapYear(year)) return 6;
        case October:
            return 0;
        case May:
            return 1;
        case August:
            return 2;
        case February:
            if (isLeapYear(year)) return 2;
        case March:
        case November:
            return 3;
        case June:
            return 4;
        case September:
        case December:
            return 5;
        case April:
        case July:
            return 6;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}

int dayOfWeek(const size_t month, const size_t day, const size_t year)
{
    return div(day + getMonthValue(month, year) + getYearValue(year) + getCenturyValue(year), 7).rem;
}

void getInput(size_t &month, size_t &day, size_t &year)
{
    std::cout << "Enter the month (1-12): ";
    month = getSanitizedNum();

    std::cout << "Enter the day (1-31): ";
    day = getSanitizedNum();

    std::cout << "Enter the year: ";
    year = getSanitizedNum();
}

int main()
{
    size_t month = 0;
    size_t day = 0;
    size_t year = 0;
    do
    {
        getInput(month, day, year);
        std::cout << "The day of the week is " << weekDays[dayOfWeek(month, day, year)] << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Run the program again (y/N): ";  // signify n as default with capital letter
    } while ('y' == getSanitizedChar());
}
```

Comment: In practice, you *never* want to write core feature of time libraries yourself.  They are maddeningly complex to get correct, and what's correct today might not be correct tomorrow.  If this wasn't a homework assignment, I would suggest learning to use [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/date_time.html).

Comment: @Chuu very good point. I was amazed by [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result?rq=1) the first time I saw it. Never did I think telling time could be so complicated as to actually account for situations like that. I'm glad those time libraries take care of that for me!

Comment: No leap year before 1582. Assuming Gregorian calendar.

Comment: *"This function should take the first two digits of the year (that is, the century)"* [Not necessarily true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21st_century) (In fact, for most years it's wrong).

Comment: There is [madness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) in this sort of code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is improper in a few ways:

> ```
> std::string *weekDays = new std::string[7] {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
> ```

Not only is this a global variable (no `const`), but it's being dynamically allocated without being deallocated with `delete` somewhere.  Plus, it can be deallocated anywhere, and possibly more than once if you're not careful.  Either way, since `std::string` already does its own memory management, just leave out `new`.

Assuming no C++11 (no access to [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)), you should end up with this:

```
const std::string weekDays[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
```

In C++, it's also best to leave the `[]` empty when initializing a C array.  The compiler will determine the correct size by itself, so you don't need to worry about keeping it up-to-date yourself.

Answer (score 22):

I'll just focus on `getMonthValue()`:

> ```
> int getMonthValue(const size_t month, const size_t year)
> {
>     switch (month) {
>         case January:
>             if (isLeapYear(year)) return 6;
>         case October:
>             return 0;
>         case May:
>             return 1;
>         …
> ```

The month and year parameters aren't sizes.  Don't use `size_t` when you just mean `unsigned int`.  However, you also had `bool isLeapYear(const int year)` — why the inconsistency in the type of `year`?  Furthermore, you have a perfectly good `Months` enum defined.  Why not rename it using the singular and use that?  You're implicitly comparing `size_t` and `Months` in the switch block anyway.

Instead of the switch block, I'd use a lookup table.  Actually, two lookup tables: one for leap years and one for non-leap years.  A data-driven design would have less code.

```
int getMonthValue(int month, int year) {
    const static int NON_LEAP_VALS[] = { 0xDEAD, 0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5 },
                         LEAP_VALS[] = { 0xDEAD, 6, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5 };
    return (isLeapYear(year)) ? LEAP_VALS[month] : NON_LEAP_VALS[month];
}
```

Comment: Is the use of dummy `0xDEAD` entry instead of using `[month+1]` index an instance of data-driven design?

Answer (score 15):

```
bool isLeapYear(const int year)
{
    if (0 == (year % 400) || (0 == (year % 4) && (year % 100))) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

This is nitpicky, but this is a bit unreadable to me. The inconsistent use of parentheses makes me think hard about order of evaluation.

Also, you use `0 ==` to express a false value, but you don't use `0 !=` to express a true value, which I also find inconsistent.

Also, the `if/else` is a bit redundant.

I would rewrite this as:

```
bool isLeapYear(const int year)
{
    return (year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0));
}
```

or if not using `== 0`:

```
bool isLeapYear(const int year)
{
    return !(year % 400) || (!(year % 4) && (year % 100));
}
```

Comment: I also think the `year % 100` logic is incorrect - it is a leap year if it is divisible by 4 and *not* 100.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy `year % 100` is the same as writing `year % 100 != 0`, as any non-zero result is equivalent to `true`.

Comment: The way you have it, yes. I think his original logic is flawed, though.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I don't see why. `==` has higher precedence than `&&`, the `0 == (year % 4)` will be evaluated before `(year % 100)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: While what you have is synactically correct, it's more human readable to use: `return ((year % 400) == 0) || (((year % 4) == 0) && ((year % 100) != 0));`

Answer (score 3):

I got the code and gave an improvement based on the comments here and I changed some things mainly the function `isLeapYear` because it is not necessary to create a function inside the iostream already has the `__isleap` is running 100%: https://pastebin.com/7xsM2CSF

```
#include <limits> //numeric_limits
#include <iostream>
//https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67636/is-it-friday-yet
//dayOfWeek.cpp

enum Months { January=1, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December};

const std::string weekDays[7]={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

/**
 * Makes sure data isn't malicious, and signals user to re-enter proper data if invalid
 * getSanitizedNum
 */
int getInt()
{
    int input = 0;
    while(!(std::cin>>input))
    {
        // clear the error flag that was set so that future I/O operations will work correctly
        std::cin.clear();
        // skips to the next newline
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "\n\tInvalid input.\n\tPlease enter a positive number: ";
    }
    return input;
}

/**
 * Safetly grabs and returns a lowercase version of the character (if the lowercase exists)
 * getSanitizedChar
 */
char32_t getChar()
{
    // absorb newline character (if existant) from previous input
    if('\n' == std::cin.peek()) std::cin.ignore();
    return std::tolower(std::cin.get());
}

int getCenturyValue(int year)
{
    return (2 * (3 - div(year / 100, 4).rem));
}

int getYearValue(int year)
{
    int mod = year % 100;
    return (mod + div(mod, 4).quot);
}

int getMonthValue(int month, int year) 
{
    const static int NON_LEAP_VALS[] = { 0xDEAD, 0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5 },
                         LEAP_VALS[] = { 0xDEAD, 6, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5 };

  return (__isleap(year) ? LEAP_VALS[month] : NON_LEAP_VALS[month]);
}
/*
int getMonthValue(int month, int year)
{
    switch (month) 
    {
        case January:
            if (__isleap(year)) return 6;
        case October:
            return 0;
        case May:
            return 1;
        case August:
            return 2;
        case February:
            if (__isleap(year)) return 2;
        case March:
        case November:
            return 3;
        case June:
            return 4;
        case September:
        case December:
            return 5;
        case April:
        case July:
            return 6;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
*/
int dayOfWeek(int day, int month, int year)
{
    return div(day + getMonthValue(month, year) + getYearValue(year) + getCenturyValue(year), 7).rem;
}

void getInput(int &day, int &month, int &year)
{
 int meses[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
 do{
    do{
       std::cout << "\n\tEnter the day (1-31): ";
       day = getInt();
      }while(day < 1 || day > 31);

    do{  
       std::cout << "\n\tEnter the month (1-12): ";
       month = getInt();
      }while(month < 1 || month > 12);

    do{  
       std::cout << "\n\tEnter the year: ";
       year = getInt();
      }while(year < 1100);

      if(__isleap(year))meses[1] = 29;

      if(day > meses[month-1])std::cout<<"\n\tO mes "<<month<<" do ano de "<<year<<" nao tem "<<day<<" dias!!!\n\n";

  }while(day > meses[month-1]);
}

int main()
{
 int day = 0;
 int month = 0;
 int year = 0;

 do{
    getInput(day, month, year);
    std::cout << "\n\tThe day of the week is " << weekDays[dayOfWeek(day, month, year)] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n\tRun the program again (y/N): ";  // signify n as default with capital letter

   }while('y' == getChar());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will be useful to explain the change you did to `isLeapYear()` and why that is better

Comment: not to reinvent the wheel if there is a specific function in the language for this.